# Running Multiple Bash Scripts parallel

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-parallel

I want to run multiple bash scripts in parallel.

example of my script running : `./test1.sh $1` and `./test2.sh $1`

I tried this: `parallel ::: "~/path/test1.sh $1" "~/path/test2.sh $1"`

Not working properly, any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `xargs`:
`echo "~/path/test1.sh $1 ~/path/test2.sh $1" | xargs -P0 -n2 /bin/bash`

`-P0` says "run all in parallel"
`-n2` passes two arguments to `/bin/bash`, in this case the script and the parameter

Comment: It's showing ~/path/test1.sh no such file or directory.

Comment: you need to put the path to your script

Comment: Given the correct path.